# Accessing a variable outside of an 'if' statement

Tags: c#

How can I make `insuranceCost` available outside the `if` statement?

```
if (this.comboBox5.Text == "Third Party Fire and Theft")
{
    double insuranceCost = 1;
}
```

Comment: What value should insuranceCost have if `comboBox5`'s text is different?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define it outside of the if statement.

```
double insuranceCost;
if (this.comboBox5.Text == "Third Party Fire and Theft")
        {
          insuranceCost = 1;
        }
```

If you are returning it from the method then you can assign it a default value or 0, otherwise you may get an error, "Use of unassigned variable";

```
double insuranceCost = 0;
```

or

```
double insuranceCost = default(double); // which is 0.0
```

Comment: I guess `0` is a lot clearer than `default(double)`. The latter is usually used with generic types where you cannot know the default value at code-write time.

Comment: @Joey, I agree, I used default to give an idea

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, you could just inline the `if` in this case (parenthesis added only for clarity):

```
double insuranceCost = (this.comboBox5.Text == "Third Party Fire and Theft") ? 1 : 0;
```

Replace `0` with whatever value you want to initialize `insuranceCost` to, if the condition does not match.

Answer (score 3):

```
    double insuranceCost = 0; 
    if (this.comboBox5.Text == "Third Party Fire and Theft") 
    { 
        insuranceCost = 1; 

    }
```

Declare it before the if statement, giving a default value. Set the value inside the if.
if you don't give a default value to the double, you will get an error at compile time.
For example

```
double GetInsuranceCost()
{
        double insuranceCost = 0; 
        if (this.comboBox5.Text == "Third Party Fire and Theft") 
        { 
            insuranceCost = 1; 

        } 
        // Without the initialization before the IF this code will not compile
        return insuranceCost;
}
```

Comment: Because u have to initialize a variable by some value to avoid warnings.

Comment: To assign a default value in case your if is not taken