# Declaring a Linq Variable

Tags: c#

Hello I'm trying to declare a linq variable but not sure the correct syntax.
For declaring normal variable you can write

```
int x = 5
string y = "apply";
```

But how would you declare a linq variable?

```
____ query = from z in Interactions select z;
```

Without using var, sorry.

Comment: Do you mean 'let'? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx

Comment: Why would you *not* use `var`?

Comment: Why not var? Explicitly specifying the type forces you to decipher what the type of the final variable will be (IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>) or may not even be possible if you are using anonymous types. In fact, casting an IQueryable to an IEnumerable would actually execute the query which is probably not what you want. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Using an explicit type makes the rest of the code easier to read, since you don't have to decipher what type the variable is. I use var quite a lot, but readability is a good reason for using explicit types in most cases.

Comment: The variable has to be declared outside the if statement but initialized within an if statement. and accessed outside the if statement. Var doesn't quite help with my situation

Comment: @user3276954, show us what you mean. I don't thing you understand what `var` is.

Comment: You can type var, then look at what Visual Studio says the actual type is.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664303/accessing-a-variable-outside-of-an-if-statement>

Comment: Var is not like var in Visual Basic 6.  It is not a variant Type and there is no performance penalty to using var over explicitly declaring the type. 
What happens is when the program compiles it determines the type of var and replace var with the type.  

But if you must, you can define it explicitly e.g.

    List<Truck> trucks = new List<Truck>();
    //Add Some trucks

    Truck truck = (from t in trucks where t.Make == VehicleMake.Ford   select t).FirstOrDefault();

    if (truck != null){
     //A truck of Make Ford was found.
    }

Comment: @gunr2171 It sounds like he understands *exactly* what `var` is.  if he needs to declare the variable before he initializes it then he cannot use `var` here, because `var` can only be used when initializing and declaring a variable at the same time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Typing the variable as `IEnumerable` would *not* execute the query.  it would *still* defer execution.  What it *would* do is ensure that any subsequent LINQ operations applied to the query will be applied in LINQ to objects, if/when the query is actually evaluated, instead of the query provider translating those LINQ operations into...whatever it would translate them into.  So it still might be a problem, but in a different way.

Comment: You can use a var a pseudo initialize it,

var fromAnonymous = { Name="", Count=0 }

then use it later in a linq query that return's an anonymous object with a string called Name and an Integer called count.

However you cannot initialize an anonymous type's members to null, because it can't deduce their type.

Comment: @Ryios There's no indication that he's using an anonymous type here, in which case he's better off just explicitly typing the variable instead of using a dummy value just to allow the use of `var`.

Comment: @Servy oops, that's the scenario I had in mind, guess I got confused writing it - specifically how a LINQ query to an ORM can result in a big intermediate dataset processed in memory instead of the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword:

```
var interactions = from z in Interactions
                   select z;
```

Assuming that `Interactions` is a collection of `Interaction` you can also use the concrete type:

```
IEnumerable<Interaction> interactions = from z in Interactions
                                        select z;
```

Both are functionally equivalent. It depends on if you know the type(you cannot use the type if you select an anonymous type) and if it's obvious. If it's not  i would always show the type, just because it's much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to at least select `z` from your interactions.

```
var query = from z in Interactions 
            select z;
```

If you don't want to use `var`

```
IEnumerable<T> query = from z in Interactions 
                       select z;
```

where `T` is the type of elements that are in `Interactions`.

Answer (score 0):

In case `Interactions` is an `IQueryable<T>` you would have to define the variable as an `IQueryable<T>`:

```
IQueryable<Interaction> interactions = from z in Interactions
                                       select z;
```

If you don't do this, using `interactions` in another LINQ query would force convert it to a LINQ to Objects query. This can be a serious problem when you execute the final query, eg with ORMs: Instead of creating a single SQL statement to the database, the intermediate results would be loaded in memory, then modified by the final query.

If you know it's an IEnumerable, you can write

```
IEnumerable<Interaction> interactions = from z in Interactions
                                       select z;
```

Note that if you return an anonymous type, or if `Interactions` contains anonymous types, you can't specify the type explicitly.

This is why it's typically preferable to declare the query variable as `var` instead of specifying a type.

Answer (score 0):

Linq Always returns a collection of objects of the type of object being enumerated.  In the event you just want a single result and your query get's a single result, you can do something like

```
TypeOfObject result = (select o from TypeOfObjectCollection where o.SomeFilter = "SomeValue" select o).FirstOrDefault();
```

Doing it this way you can define TypeOfObject result = null;  wherever you want and populate it later.